# Disabling/enabling buttons by data in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

I'm having a look at Vue.js with a view to simplifying an application which is starting to get a bit too complex with jQuery. I want to utilise the data binding so that the state of an 'Order' object automatically enables or disables certain buttons (e.g., I want the submit button to be automatically disabled unless an order, containing items, exists). I have something which partly works, with this declaration:

```
 var content = new Vue({
    el: '#content',
    computed: {
        orderExists: function () {
            return (shopOrder != null && !isEmpty(shopOrder.items));
        }
    }
});
```

I use it in a button like this:

```
<button type="button" id="btnDisplay" v-bind:disabled="!orderExists">Show Selected</button>
```

On page load, the buttons using this technique are indeed enabled/disabled correctly. However, when I add items to the order object, thereby changing its state, I'm not seeing any update in the buttons' states - they should be being enabled.

I assume I'm misunderstanding something basic about how this works with Vue.js, as I've only spent a couple of hours with it, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm why not pass the property as reactive data?

You can do something like:

```
...
computed: {
        orderExists: function () {
            this.disabled = (shopOrder != null && !isEmpty(shopOrder.items));
        }
    }
```

[Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/wanxe/068j5991/)

DP: the example is in Vue 2

Comment: This won't work because if `shopOrder` is a plain JavaScript object that hasn't been made reactive by Vue, `orderExists` will never fire when it changes and `disabled` will never update. For more info see https://vuejs.org/guide/computed.html and read the "Computed Caching vs Methods" section. Also, there's no point in making this approach a computed because the value will always be undefined since it doesn't return a value.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that Vue has to manage your data objects in order to set them up in a way where it can observe the changes to them (i.e. be made reactive). This is done by specifying the `data` option to your `Vue` creation. Something like:

```
data: {
    shopOrder: null
}
```

Then update your code like this:

```
orderExists: function () {
    return (this.shopOrder != null && !isEmpty(this.shopOrder.items));
}
```

And of course at some point you need to set `this.shopOrder` to a valid order object.

Comment: I woke in the night with this very answer myself! I realised I had neglected to make it managed data. I've been working a bit with React.js in the last year and the same thing applies there, so I should have thought of that. I just have to read up about managing data now.

Comment: Still struggling with this, actually. I think my problem may be to with the way I'm updating my shopOrder property, possibly messing up the proxying. If I assign a new object to shopOrder , as opposed to updating its properties, should this still work? That is, if I do something like 'content.shopOrder=newOrder'? Failing that, is it permissible to add new properties to an existing managed data object?

Comment: It might help to see some code in a Fiddle. You have to make sure that the object is contained within the Vue itself using the `data` option and then later referencing it with `this` in the context of methods.

Comment: Slightly awkward to condense down the problem into a Fiddle. But in any case I actually now have this working as a result of giving up on the idea of trying to keep the Vue data in sync with the existing object I was using before. I've now switched everything to use the Vue data and dispensed with the old object.